# Recently installed RAID already degraded on partition

Tags: raid, mdadm

I set up setting up a new two disk RAID1 which appeared healthy in mdstat. In a few hours, here's what I later saw when I ran `cat /proc/mdstat`.

```
Personalities : [raid1]
md1 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
      4982784 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
        resync=PENDING

md0 : active raid1 sda1[0]
      483266560 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
      bitmap: 4/4 pages [16KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

I think it's peculiar that `md0` is shown to be missing an `sdb` partition but `md1` is not. I don't think `sdb` has failed, since it is new, so how can I get `md0` fixed up?

---

From the system logs:

```
$ dmesg  | grep sdb
[    3.612217] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/465 GiB)
[    3.612219] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    3.612290] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    3.612294] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    3.612326] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    3.630283]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2
[    3.631320] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[    3.793804] md: bind<sdb1>
[    3.795337] md: bind<sdb2>
[    3.846233] md: kicking non-fresh sdb1 from array!
[    3.846240] md: unbind<sdb1>
[    3.865721] md: export_rdev(sdb1)
```

Comment: What does your system log have to say on the topic?

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt Just added the output from dmesg above.

Comment: To see what's going on you want to look at the output of... mdadm -D /dev/md0

Answer (score 2):

From one of the many Google hits on "kicking non-fresh sdb1 from array":

This can happen after an unclean shutdown (like a power fail). Usually removing and re-adding the problem device will correct the situation:

```
/sbin/mdadm /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sdb1 --remove /dev/sdb1
/sbin/mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdb1
```